# Prove that $E[Y]=\int_0^\infty P(Y>y)dy-\int_0^\infty P(Y<-y)dy$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Prove that $E[Y]=\int_0^\infty P(Y>y)dy-\int_0^\infty P(Y<-y)dy$.

Should I first prove that
$$\int_0^\infty P(Y<-y)dy=-\int_{-\infty}^0 xf_Y(x) dx$$
and $$\int_0^\infty P(Y>y)dy=\int_0^\infty xf_Y(x)dx$$
where $f_Y$ is the density function of $Y$?
Where do I go from there?

Comment: This has been asked several times on the site recently. No, PDFs are not useful, simply integrate the pointwise identity $$Y=\int_0^\infty \mathbf 1_{Y>y}\,dy-\int_0^\infty \mathbf 1_{Y<-y}\,dy.$$

Comment: Not all random variables have densities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write $$EY=\int_{-\infty}^\infty ydF_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^0 ydF_Y(y)+\int_{0}^\infty ydF_Y(y)=I_1+I_2$$Note that $$I_1=\int_{-\infty}^0 y\frac{d}{dy}dF_Y(y)\\=-\int_{-\infty}^0 P(Y\le y)dy=-\int_{0}^\infty P(Y\le -y)dy\\
\ \\ I_2=-\int_{0}^\infty ydF_Y^c(y)=\int_{0}^\infty P(Y>y) dy $$

Comment: I think for your argument to hold we need $F_Y(y) = O \left (\frac {1} {y^{\alpha}} \right )$ for some $\alpha \gt 1$ whenever $y$ is far away from the origin. Is it trivial?

Comment: This is a general statement and does not depend on the form of $F_Y$, except for integrability, which is assured for continuous random variables.